# Swift: Undefined Symbols: iTunesApplication

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, itunes, scripting-bridge

I'm trying to create Swift OS X app now, and found difficulty using ScriptingBridge.

I included proper iTunes.h file, and Xcode is not giving any error when I wrote "iTunesApplication" as type.

However, when I compile(run) the app, it gives me error :(
Does anybody know about this issue?

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_iTunesApplication", referenced from:
>        __TFC12LoveYouChloe11AppDelegate10showWindowfS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ in AppDelegate.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

And here is my code:

```
var iTunes: iTunesApplication = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier("com.apple.iTunes") as iTunesApplication
iTunes.playpause()
```

Comment: I can reproduce this. At first I thought it would just be that you've not linked against the ScriptingBridge framework, but that doesn't seem to solve it for me...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is to take the generated Objective-C Scripting Bridge header and convert it into a native Swift. I wrote a Python script ([here](https://github.com/garrett-davidson/SwiftingBridge/)) that can do that for you. You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135027/swift-itunes-scriptingbridge-linker-error/31091659#31091659) for a better explanation of what exactly is going on if you're interested.

Comment: I tried your script, unfortunately it still produces 85 errors for iTunes... Also some of the functionality doesn't work, for example i can't set the soundVolume property...

Answer (score -2):

Instead of

```
var iTunes: iTunesApplication = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier("com.apple.iTunes")
```

use

```
var iTunes: AnyObject = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier("com.apple.iTunes")
```

Sometimes the compiler gets confused when you are accessing two or more properties in a row(no idea why) so you may need to use a temporary variable. E.g.:

Instead of:

```
let songName: String = iTunes.playlists[0].songs[0].name
```

Try:

```
let song: AnyObject = iTunes.playlists[0].songs[0]
let songName = song.name
```

Or Alternatively the faster (this also works if you declare `iTunes` as an `SBApplication`) :

```
let songName: String = iTunes.valueAtIndex(0, inPropertyWithKey: "playlists").valueAtIndex(0, inPropertyWithKey: "songs").valueForKey("name")
```

**EDIT:**
You can also generate the .swift headers as specified here: https://github.com/tingraldi/SwiftScripting

Comment: how is it letting you access playlists (which is not a property of AnyObject)

Comment: Also does not work for me, in fact it doesn't even compile.