# Swift iTunes ScriptingBridge linker error

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, itunes, scripting-bridge

I have searched extensively for an answer to this, but have found none, so I'm asking here. I am trying to read the current track in iTunes using Swift, but whenever I try to reference any of the iTunes classes (iTunesApplication, iTunesTrack, etc) I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:  
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_iTunesApplication", referenced from:  
      __TFC8WAILT_v213iTunesWrapper17getSongWithFormatfS0_FTSS3sepSS10timeOnLeftSb_SS  in iTunesWrapper.o  
      __TMaCSo17iTunesApplication in iTunesWrapper.o  
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64  
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks,
-tlf
P.S. If I use Obj-C, it works just fine. It only errors when I am using Swift.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395805/swift-undefined-symbols-itunesapplication

Answer (score 1):

Because of Swift's strong static typing, it has issues linking with code that it doesn't have either an implementation or a binary for. Therefore to use an Objective-C Bridging Header with it, you will most likely need to use generic `SBObject`s because Swift knows the implementation of those, even though your .h declares the other classes.

An alternative is to use a script to generate a native Swift file with declarations that it can see and use. [Here](https://github.com/garrett-davidson/SwiftingBridge/) is a Python script (full disclosure: it's mine) that generates Objective-C Scripting Bridge headers then creates a native Swift version. This avoids Linker Errors and the aforementioned SBObject generic typing.

Comment: Since the introduction of AppleScriptObjC in Snow Leopard the Scripting Bridge framework is pretty obsolete. The integration with Objective-C and Swift is quite easy and AppleScriptObjC much faster than SB

Comment: Too bad there isn't a AppleScriptSwift…